# Is it possible for a multithreaded julia program to not exit()

Tags: websocket, julia

I have some code in my app that uses an `HTTP.WebSockets` client and errors in the receive loop.  I have a try catch surrounding that that calls `exit()` on caught error.  But I noticed while the client did hit that branch and stopped running the program as a whole with its other threads did not quit as in it did not return control to the terminal.

Is the `exit()` being caught by the websocket code?
Or is something else at play calling `exit()` from a different thread?

Update:

After second thought I think I should be rethrow()ing my exceptions to the root level.  It still doesn't make sense exit doesn't fully exit the task or program but hopefully this works.

Answer (score 0):

Rethrowing the error to the top does work. If you want the program not to exit, you could create an atomic flag variable such as

```
all_ok = Threads.Atomic{Bool}(true)
```

checked with `all_ok[]`, and when you catch an error you would flag this in the catch routine with `all_ok[] = false`. Each worker thread would then need to check the all_ok[] flag periodically and quit when it is false.